# Evaluate the limit $\;\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin\bigg(\pi\sqrt{n^2+n-3}\bigg)$

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

Evaluate the limit$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin\bigg(\pi\sqrt{n^2+n-3}\bigg)$$ and $n\in N$

**My Approach:**

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin\bigg(\pi\sqrt{n^2+n-3}\bigg)\implies \lim_{n \to \infty} {\pm}\sin\bigg(n\pi-\pi\sqrt{n^2+n-3}\bigg)$

$\implies \pm\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin\bigg[\pi\bigg(n-\sqrt{n^2+n-3}\bigg)\bigg]$

$\pm\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin\left[\dfrac{\pi\bigg(n-\sqrt{n^2+n-3}\bigg)\bigg(n+\sqrt{n^2+n-3}\bigg)}{(n+\sqrt{n^2+n-3}\bigg)}\right]$

$\implies \pm\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin\left[\dfrac{\pi\bigg(n^{2}-\left(\sqrt{n^2+n-3}\right)^2\bigg)}{(n+\sqrt{n^2+n-3}\bigg)}\right]$

$\implies \pm \lim_{n\to \infty}\sin\left[\dfrac{\pi\left(-n+3\right)}{n\left(1+\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{3}{n^{2}}}\right)}\right]$

$\implies \pm \lim_{n\to \infty} \sin\left[\dfrac{\pi n \left(-1+\dfrac{3}{n}\right)}{n\left(1+\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{3}{n^{2}}}\right)}\right]$

$\implies \pm \sin\left(\dfrac{-\pi}{2}\right)\implies\pm 1$

**Doubt:** Is my solution and answer correct because my book does not contain answer to this question

Other Approaches are also welcomed.

Comment: It is fine but you should write $(-1)^{n}$ instead of $\pm$.

Comment: You haven't answered the question! Remember that the limit when it exists is unique... Moreover, I would suggest that you write sentences about what is happening, rather than a list of equations. It will avoid you to speak of something that may not even exist.

Comment: Correct answer for such case: limit does not exist

Comment: Does your textbook really say "evaluate the limit"? That phrase is typically used for limits that exist.

Comment: This is effectively a solution-verification question, I have tagged it as such. Please (1) Point out parts of your proof that you think are problematic (2) Provide the source of this question and what your background is (3) Search for similar questions using [Approach0](approach0.xyz) and see if your attempt is resolved by an already present proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\sqrt{n^2 + n - 3} = n\Big(1 + \frac{n-3}{n^2}\Big)^{1/2}$

By binomial expansion, we have

$$
(1 + x)^{\frac{1}{2}} = 1 + \frac{x}{2} - \frac{x^2}{8} + \ldots
$$

Plug in $x = \frac{n-3}{n^2}$ and calculate the first two terms and simplify to get

$$
\sqrt{n^2 + n - 3} = n + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{13}{8n} + \ldots
$$

When $n \to \infty$ every term after the first two terms will vanish. Hence for $n \in N$,

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sin(\pi\sqrt{n^2 + n - 3}) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sin(n\pi + \pi/2)) = \lim_{n \to \infty}(-1)^n
$$

Hence the limit does not exist as it will either be $+1$ or $-1$ depending of if $n$ is even or odd.

Comment: Can you  Provide Proof for $(\sqrt{n^2+n-3})$ I know it is using binomial expansion.

Comment: Also I think $\sin\left(n\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)=\pm 1$

Comment: @mathophile Added and updated

Answer (score 1):

(A) $L=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin\bigg(\pi\sqrt{n^2+n-3}\bigg)$ where $n$ is real : Does not Exist.

(B) $L=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin\bigg(\pi\sqrt{n^2+n-3}\bigg)$ where $n$ is **Even Natural** : $L=+\sin(\pi/2)=+1$.

We can see that $L=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin\bigg(\pi\sqrt{n^2+n-3}\bigg)$ gives :

$L=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin\bigg(\pi\sqrt{n^2+n+1/4-1/4-3}\bigg)$

$L=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin\bigg(\pi\sqrt{(n+1/2)^2-13/4}\bigg)$

$L=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin\bigg(\pi(n+1/2)\bigg)$

$L=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin\bigg(\pi n + \pi / 2\bigg)$

$L=\pm \sin(\pi / 2)$ ( We can think that in the limit , we get a sequence where the value toggles between $+1$ & $-1$ , though strictly speaking , **there is no Unique Limit** in this Case here )

**A little tweaking in the Exercise will give the Unique Limit :**

We can make it that $n$ is Even Natural , then
$L=+\sin(\pi / 2)=+1$

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$ \pi n-\pi\sqrt{n^2+n-3}  =\pi \frac{3-n}{n+\sqrt{n^2+n-3}} \to-\frac \pi 2$$

then for $n$ odd

$$\sin\left(\pi\sqrt{n^2+n-3}\right)=\sin\left(\pi n-\pi\sqrt{n^2+n-3}\right) \to -1$$

while for $n$ even

$$\sin\left(\pi\sqrt{n^2+n-3}\right)=-\sin\left(\pi n-\pi\sqrt{n^2+n-3}\right) \to 1$$